# Deploying web app on HTTPS automatically makes my AJAX calls HTTPS too?

Tags: ajax, https

My application will be deployed on HTTPS (currently it is in development and running on HTTP).

Will deploying the web app on HTTPS automatically make my AJAX calls HTTPS as well? I am using relative URLs in the AJAX calls, so i am thinking that when the absolute URL is constructed, HTTPS will be appended automatically.

please let me know. thanks for your response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using relative URLs, then yes.

However, it is really important to test this before running live, as certain browsers(at least IE6) will display a really alarming warning if you try to load resources like images using a non-https connection.